# For every github commit I see a github clone

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a private github repository which I use it as github pages to host a blog.

Every time I push a commit, I see a github clone record in the insights tab(traffic) of that repository. For example: I pushed 10 commits on a single day. When I check the traffic tab it shows 10 clones and 1 unique cloner.

That isn't the case with other private repositories. What am I missing here?

Comment: Youve uses the pages tag; does that mean you private repo hosts a github-pages site? If so, that might explain the traffic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you push to a GitHub Pages repository, a GitHub server will clone your repository, build it, and send it to the GitHub Pages server.  That will all be done with an internal app, which is likely why you're seeing a single cloner and one clone for each time you've pushed.

If you push multiple commits at once, the Pages service will only build once for the update, so you can check by pushing multiple commits at once.

If you're concerned, you can reach out to the GitHub support team and they can check the logs for you, but I wouldn't be worried about it.  It's an accurate, if somewhat surprising, side effect of using GitHub Pages.